# Symbols on Google Maps polyline always rotate

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, svg, rotation

I am looking for a way to prevent custom symbols (defined by SVG path) from rotating relative to the polyline. I'd like to have them a fixed absolute rotation angle.

http://jsfiddle.net/25Nce/10/

```
var symbolTwo = {
    path: 'M -1,0 A 1,1 0 0 0 -3,0 1,1 0 0 0 -1,0M 1,0 A 1,1 0 0 0 3,0 1,1 0 0 0 1,0M -3,3 Q 0,5 3,3',
    strokeColor: '#00F',
    rotation: 45
};
```

The sample contains two polylines with the same symbols and you can see that the symbols are rotated relative to the direction of the polyline. Is there a way to specify an absolute rotation angle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [`fixedRotation`-property of the IconSequence](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#IconSequence) to `true`

[**http://jsfiddle.net/25Nce/13/**](http://jsfiddle.net/25Nce/13/)